# How to return an array from PHP script when an HTTP request is sent from javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

Hi I'm new to PHP and I'm stuck on an issue,
I want to send a HTTP request to a `PHP` script and it should return a 2x2 array. But with my code I'm receiving nothing.

`index.html:`

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", "get_info.php");
        xhr.onload = function () {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);                    
        };
        xhr.send();
    </script>    
</body>
</html>
```

`get_info.php:`

```
<?php
    $return_array = [[1, "h"],[2, "he"],[3, "hel"],[4, "hell"],[5, "hello"]];
    return $return_array;
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`json_encode()` that array, and `echo` (not return!) the resulting json string:

```
<?php
    $return_array = [[1, "h"],[2, "he"],[3, "hel"],[4, "hell"],[5, "hello"]];
    echo json_encode($return_array);
    // remove the trailing ?> just to make sure you don't send an unwanted newline, space or smth
```

Then in javascript

```
var myArray = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText); 
console.log(myArray);
```

to make a js array out of it again.

Some docs and related reads:

- [php: json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)
- [JSON wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)
- [javascript: JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Answer (score 0):

Use `echo` instead of `return` ... this isn't a function that was called; it is a code snippet that simply puts dynamic data in place of static text.